# How to loop this if the password or username entered is not correct

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, if-statement, authentication

How can I loop this if the password or username entered is not correct and for only 3 attempts?

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {            
    if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

        if (userTf.getText().equals(dat.getUserName()) & passTf.getText().equals(dat.getPassWord())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello You are an Authorized User!!!",null,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);         
            System.exit(1);          
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password or Username!!!",null,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);               
        }           
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is just regular old Java (not Android or using a particular Framework), you have a few options...

**You could create a *flag*** outside of this method (but visable from within the method) that keeps track of the number of times that the user's login failed. Then, when the keyPressed activity is called, your code should check if the user has reached maximum tries and do something accordingly.

Here's one idea for a global flag and a set maximum number of allowed failed log-in attempts.

```
public class MyClass {
    private int logInAttempts = 0;
    private final int MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 3;

....
}
```

Then in your method it could look like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {            
  if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
     if(logInAttempts == MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS) {
        // they've failed to login too many times
        // lock them out, start a timer, or whatever
    } else {
     // go on to check if login is correct
    if (userTf.getText().equals(dat.getUserName()) & passTf.getText().equals(dat.getPassWord())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello You are an Authorized User!!!",null,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);         
        System.exit(1);          
    } else {
        // if using a flag for login attempts, you need to increment it
        // when the user fails logging in
        logInAttempts++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password or Username!!!",null,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);               
    }           
}
```

}

**Please note** that if you use this flagging idea to track user's failed login attempts, you need to increment it when the user fails to login, as I've done before the "Incorrect Password or Username!!!!"

I hope that helps!